# Disabling mouse in Swing

Tags: java, swing

I would like to disable the mouse cursor not the text cursor in my Swing application. I found the following code which has managed to hide the cursor but not disabling its function.

```
// Transparent 16 x 16 pixel cursor image.
BufferedImage cursorImg = new BufferedImage(16, 16, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
// Create a new blank cursor.
Cursor blankCursor = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(cursorImg, new Point(0, 0), "blank cursor");
// Set the blank cursor to the JFrame.
getContentPane().setCursor(blankCursor);
```

Any solution please?

Answer (score 2):

Two solutions:

1. You can call on all your components: setEditable(false). But actually, even that won't do it perfectly, better to do setEnabled(false).
2. If you are using a JFrame, you can use the JLayeredPane's GlassPane. Set that to setEnabled(true) and it will intercept all mouse events

Comment: I don't want to disable the components. All I want is disabling the mouse.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to disable mouse?

Comment: I want to use a touchscreen.

Comment: @shb2789 Well, when you use a touch screen, if I'm not wrong, when you get focus on any item, it just makes the mouse cursor disappear, try it...

Comment: @shb2789 - so, if I have a tablet there is no mouse that needs to be disabled, but if I have a mouse+keyboard+touchscreen you're going to _prevent me_ from using my mouse, even if I prefer it over poking at my screen? That's a pretty user-hostile design.

Comment: must be consume() in some cases for GlassPane